# Why do quantum objects slow down when volume increases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, volume

I was reading [this](https://news.mit.edu/2019/quark-speed-proton-neutron-pairs-0220) article about the EMC effect and saw this quote

> “In quantum mechanics, anytime you increase the volume over which an object is confined, it slows down,” Schmidt says. “If you tighten up the space, it speeds up. That’s a known fact.”

And was trying to figure out why and haven't been able to find a conclusive article or answer. MY guess is that the interactions with other quantum objects is where they get most of their velocity, thus greater volumes means less intense interactions?

Answer (score 12):

This is a loosely-phrased consequence of the uncertainty principle, which says that the product of the position uncertainty and the momentum uncertainty is larger than some minimum value that you can find from Fourier analysis of the wavefunction:

$$
\sigma_x\sigma_p>\hbar/2
$$

One way to compute the uncertainty in an observable is to take the difference between the mean of the square and the square of the mean:

$$
\sigma_p^2 = \left<p^2\right> - \left<p\right>^2
$$

If I have a particle in a "small box," then its position uncertainty is small. If the box is stationary, then the mean momentum is zero, $\left<p\right>=0$. The uncertainty principle requires that the mean momentum-squared, which is related to the kinetic energy $p^2/2m$, must be large.

If you solve the Schrodinger equation for a particle in a box, the size of the box shows up in the denominator for the energy of the ground state — a result directly related to the uncertainty principle.

Note the converse, as stated in your question, is *allowed* rather than inevitable. If you have a trapped particle and you make its trap bigger, the particle *may* transition to a lower-energy state which didn't exist in the smaller trap.

Comment: Mathematically this makes sense. But conceptually, why does the particle "need" to speed up to fit the math? What mechanism is causing it to speed up outside of, that's just how the math is. Do we know?

Comment: To come up with a conceptual mechanism, consider a specific system. For the hydrogen-like ions (including the neutral hydrogen atom) , the "virial theorem" suggests that small "orbits" must have more kinetic energy. For the harmonic oscillator, the size of the ground state is related to the stiffness of the spring. For electron-degenerate matter, you might like a book on white dwarf stars and their thermal properties.

Answer (score 5):

It's just like musical instruments: the bigger the instrument, the lower the frequency and the longer the wavelength of the sound that leaks out of it. In the quantum world, momentum is inversely proportional to wavelength. So, the lowest modes will have lower momentum/energy in a bigger box.

Comment: This is actually pretty great answer. So in this case is momentum proportional to the "speed" mentioned in the article? Since to me this explains why momentum would increase (smaller wavelength) but not necessarily why it would move faster. Either way it's a pretty good answer.

Comment: @TheJeran I think the article is using "speed" in the sense of the classical $v=p/m$.